# Concurrency in Swing.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency

I seem to need some explaining on proper techniques using Swing.

I am a recent graduate and have just built my first program to transform CSV files from third party vendors into a readable format for the ETL tool my job uses.

Currently I start with a main method that calls a simple frame to ask the user to find the file. It is a standalone class that uses JFileReader and the user selects the file using that. Once they select the file and hit okay I dispose of that frame and load another frame that is a completely different class. I do this in one of the methods of said class. I do this multiple times until I reach the last frame which then before its method ends calls creates a new instance of the first class again.

So pretty much the sequence goes like this.

New class1 - dispose class1 - new class2 -dispose class2 - new class3 - dispose class3 - new class1.

This program works great for what it needs to do. But for myself I know this has to be the wrong way to do it. As far as I know when a method ends all members of that method are then unreferenced. How is it that my program continues to loop in this form? Is there something about a class that extends JFrame that gives it control? Am I just passing control from one Frame to another? Also would this eventually cause a memory problem if used enough (are the older classes really getting disposed of)?

Comment: What is the relevant code in your last class?

Comment: The last class essentially takes all the information provided by the previous classes and creates a swingworker to do a long computational method in the background while displaying a loading screen. Once the computation is done the loading screen is disposed of and it creates a new instance of the very first class (to start the process over) and then disposes of itself.

Comment: So the re-creation of the first screen is intentional and expected?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=programming+stack+vs+heap

Comment: Yes the creation of the first screen again is intentional and expected. It was my way of 'looping' the program. I think now it may not be the proper way.

Comment: As for stack vs heap I understand that to a point but even when my method ends the new frame persists. Shouldn't once the method ends all local variables of the method be destroyed (that would include the new class and the frame created from that class) or because  that frame still has references the JVM will not collect it?

Comment: @Warsum In my opinion, what you are describing sounds like it can be solved using State Pattern.  I used this pattern to create a (process) Wizard. Are you in need to create something that help you transition from one page (class) to a specific page (class)? Does this sound like what you are trying to do? If it is, I can recommend a simple code example for you to play with.

Comment: @hfontanez yes that is similar to what I need to do. Each class I would like to be its own 'page'. If I could get all these pages drawn in the same 'book' (frame) that would be great. But I must also take values from previous pages and pass them into the constructor of a new page. If what you discuss is similar please share.

Comment: I will upload my code somewhere and I will post a link here when I am done. The prototype I created is extremely simple: Three panels with a JLabel and two navigation buttons (previous and next). The Context class controls the transition from one panel (page) to the next.

Comment: Go to my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/91upteaw) public location. The concrete (singleton) state classes could be improved using enum. I hope this helps you get started.  I got the idea from this [State Pattern Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/state_pattern.htm).